# Android ActionMode replace Action Items dynamically

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have implemented an ActionMode via ActionBarSherlock (thanks Jake Wharton for ABS!).

Anyways, i am calling the
`mActionMode.invalidate();` each time i click on a ListView item, which also increments/decrements a checkedCounter.

Then inside the public boolean `onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, android.view.Menu menu)` , I have to set the ActionMode contents according to the value of the checkedCounter.

Code for the onPrepareActionMode is below :

> ```
>     public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode,
>                 android.view.Menu menu) {
>             Log.d("ASDASD", "INSIDE ONPREPARE!");
>             if (mActionMode == null) {
>                 MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
>                 inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextualmultiple, menu);
>                 return false;
>             }
>             if (checkedCount == 0) {
>                 mActionMode.finish();
>             } else if (checkedCount == 1 && mActionMode != null) {
>                 mActionMode.setTitle(checkedCount + " Message Selected");
>                 MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
>                 inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextualmultiple, menu);
>                 return true;
>             } else if (checkedCount > 1) {
>                 mActionMode.setTitle(checkedCount + " Messages Selected");
>                 MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
>                 inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextual, menu);
>                 return true;
>             }
>             return true;
>         }
> ```

NOW, the problem is that, when the checkCount is 1, it inflates the menu with say, 3 items in it.
But, when the counter increments to 2, it inflates the other menu with 1 item, BUT adds on to the previously inflated menu, without nullifying the contents first.
I.E.; now the ActionMode has 2 of previous + 1 of current in the Contextual ActionBar!

How can i change my code to remove the previously existing menu items from the ActionMode when the `mActionMode.invalidate()` is called?

P.S. : the onCreateActionMode() function is empty, as the onPrepareActionMode() does everything, including when the mActionMode is null and has a menu to be inflated for the first time.

Answer (score 8):

haha! i found a ridiculously simple solution to the ridiculous problem!

for anyone else that MIGHT encounter this problem, just add a `menu.clear();` statement before all inflate() statements, and that's it!